# Declaring a public array in VB.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I know that to declare a string in VB I would use the line

```
Dim ExString As String
```

And to declare a global string I'd use

```
Public Shared Property ExString As String
```

Which I'd access using (assuming it was saved in a class called GlobalVars)

```
MsgBox(GlobalVars.ExString)
```

I also know that to declare a string array it's

```
Dim ExString(3) As String
```

However declaring a public array doesn't seem to work the same, the line:

```
Public Shared Property ExString(3) As String
```

Doesn't seem to work.
I was wondering how I go about declaring a public array of strings in visual basic?
I'm using Visual Studio 2010 if that makes a difference.

Thanks in advance

Comment: is this in a class or module?

Comment: To declare a global `string`, you can do various things. For example: `Public Shared ExString As String` (and the `Shared` part is also not strictly required; has its specific meaning which you should know before using it).

Comment: @Jeremy It's a class.

Comment: Array can not be declared as a shared. You can create instance of your forms and redefine array as per you need. Let me know if this make sense.

Comment: @DotNetWeblineindia that's just wrong

Comment: @DotNetWeblineindia I get it. I only need to save 5 values so I'll just use 5 individual strings. It's for a school project and we get more "points" for using more features of the programming language. I'll just slip an array in somewhere else. Thanks

Comment: @Waescher If that's wrong what is the case? Mixed reports here haha

Comment: You can create global constant for that. See my answer below.

Comment: @DatBrummie Arrays can be declared as shared. If you use my answer below, you can score with an language feature called Collection Initializers (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293617(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @DatBrummie : got it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add the length (3) to your variable, because Visual Studio will nag:

> Identifier expected.

But you can do something like:

```
Public Shared Property MyString As String() = New String() { "abc", "def", "ghi"}
```

Comment: And would I access this in the same way?

Comment: MsgBox(GlobalVars.MyString(4)) for example?

Comment: It is an normal array which is just exposed as static/shared property, of course you can.

Comment: Alright thanks. What if I don't know the contents of the 3 values? Would I have to put { "", "", ""}?

Comment: Just skip the assignment completely, so the Array is Nothing initially and can be assigned as soon as you know the values.

Comment: If you don't know how many strings you'll have, use a List(Of String) instead so it can be increased easily without ReDim. ReDim'ming is so 90's ;)

Comment: And once I know the value I'd fill it with; MyString(0) = txtUser.text or something along those lines?

Comment: No I know the amount of strings, I just don't know the values. It's basically storing log in details. The username, password, name, account type. So it can't be filled until the user logs in

Comment: This would be a direct assignment to an element of an array but you don't have an array if it was not assigned yet. So you might assign it with MyString = New String() { "bla" }.

Comment: In this case you should build a simple class object with those properties and hold that to store values. Lets say you have a class called UserInfo with properties UserName, Password, Name, etc. This is typesafe and much easier to code with as working with arrays like If (Info(0) = "") Then ...

Comment: If I assign it with MyString = New String() { "bla" } would it only have one element, and so crash upon trying to assign something to MyString(1)?

Comment: It would have one element which you can read and write as you want afterwards. But you cannot access MyString(2) because the value is outside of the array bounds. So, trust me: Use a List(Of String) or even better, build a UserInfo helper class which you can hold as shared prop as well

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. How would I build a class to store it? That seems like the best alternative, none of this stuff has really been covered in class though so I'm not sure what I'm doing

Comment: That's way too much to answer in detail here in the comments. Basically, you have to build a class, add the properties and make a property of the type of that class. There's nothing special about it, but if you're not familiar with classes by now, I'd suggest that you spend some time googling for terms like "Value Objects", "POCO", "DTO".

Comment: Ah yeah I'm still getting started in VB really so I'm not familiar with a lot of things. I try to learn as much as I can but it gets overwhelming sometimes. Just to get the program functioning I might just save them as separate strings for now, and work on something more complex on the side just for the extra points

Comment: Every programmer was new to programming once - even Jon Skeet :) So I'd suggest you use this approach and assign your array as soon as you know the values like MyString = New String() { "Waescher", "passw@rd" } or - if you want to be able to add values during the program execution, assign a new list like MyStrings = New List(Of String)() and you can add, overwrite and remove strings whenever you want. Just do MyStrings.Add("passw@rd") to add a new one.

Comment: Given that I know how many elements I need,  I was going to just follow the instructions in your original answer and just create it using blank elements { "", "", "", ""}  I don't think I'm going to need to be able to add values during execution, only assigning to the elements

Comment: Maybe one day I'll be able to create a class:) thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one instance of the variable, you need a static member. Static members belong to the class, not an individual object. VB calls them Shared members because you can imagine the same variable is shared between all of the instances:

```
Public Class Form1

Public Shared ShuffleArray() As Integer

End Class


ReDim Form1.ShuffleArray(52)
Form1.ShuffleArray(0) = 10
```

Alternatively, you can create a module that contains the variable. Modules are a special type of class where two magic things happen. First, all of the members are in the global namespace so you don't need the module name to access them. Second, all members are automatically static.

```
Module GlobalConstants

Public ShuffleArray() As Integer

End Module


ReDim ShuffleArray(51)
GlobalConstants.ShuffleArray(0) = 10
Console.WriteLine(ShuffleArray(0)) ' output : 10
```

I think this will serve your purpose in case you do not want to fix your 5 values.

Comment: Still trying to get my head around what this means.. I'm fairly novice at this

Comment: I think he has a fixed array - so there's no need for a ReDim. If he wants to have a "dynamic array", he should use a List(Of String).

Comment: @ DatBrummie : It is nothing just a separation of global variables.