# How do I declare an array of type integer in vb.net?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I need to declare an array of type integer at the module level, but not sure how to do so.

Comment: Dim myArr(10) as Integer

Comment: Seriously, how much research did you do before asking this? [Arrays in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx)

Comment: Actual this is a two part question, you answered the first. The second is about Scope is often confusing. Here is a useful reference for scope https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx

Comment: LOL - I love this thread. Gary beards, to other newbies, all over the map for what is being dismissed as a question with an obvious answer, but missing the mark. Please don't be put off by the occasional nastiness to new posters. We all mean well (I hope, although I wonder sometimes) even if we are mean while "answering." That said, Google is always friendly - at least on the technical stuff.

Comment: Would have been quicker to Google this. Google has about 90% of the answers if you take the time to look

Answer (score 4):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx
Array of length 5:

```
Dim numbers(4) As Integer
```

Array with specific values:

```
Dim numbers = New Integer() {1, 2, 4, 8}
```

Comment: In VB.NET, the size initializer is actually the upper bound of the array, not the number of elements, so `Dim numbers(4) As Integer` would create an array of length 5.  This is different from languages whose syntax is inherited from C, like C#.

Comment: @Panzercrisis Right, I forgot VB is dumb. Fixed it.

Comment: @Zaggler fixed it

Comment: VB isn't dumb haha but I can see how one would think that.

Comment: @johncliffe see http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/A+bad+workman+blames+his+tools

Comment: Actually I made an edit because this is wrong. See this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32584513/declaring-a-public-array-in-vb-net. You need to declare it `Dim numbers As Integer() = New Integer() {1, 2, 3, 4} `. I tested it and it would give "nothing" value to my array if I declared it your way.

Comment: My edit was rejected, because you need to change it yourself. @johncliffe could you edit your answer so that people are not confused ?

Answer (score -1):

For an array of size 100.

```
Dim IntegerArray(99) As Integer
```

For another size, replace 99 with a number of your choice.

Comment: Thanks @Zaggler. Fixed.